# Check request type in Django

Tags: django, coding-style

While it is recommended to use the following construct to check whether request is POST,

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    pass
```

It is likely that people will find

```
if request.POST:
    pass
```

to be more elegant and concise.

Are there any reasons not to use it, apart from personal preference?

Comment: I think this is one place that Sinatra uses a better approach: you handle POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, etc with a different handler.

I have a function called dispatch in my API generator to split the calls according to HTML request method.

Comment: @Matthew Schinckel doesn't that lead to the code duplication or at least duplication of calls to functions needed to obtain some common data, say list of users?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The documentation is clear about this:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.POST

> It's possible that a request can come in via POST with an empty POST dictionary -- if, say, a form is requested via the POST HTTP method but does not include form data. Therefore, you shouldn't use if request.POST to check for use of the POST method; instead, use if request.method == "POST" (see above).

```
>>> # assume an empty POST request would be treated as a dict
>>> bool({})
False
>>> # it would be a POST request, but request.POST would evaluate to False
```

Comment: Has this standard changed since 2022?